# Force mobile safari form assistant to only cycle through one form

Tags: iphone, ios, mobile-safari

In mobile Safari when using an html form the 'form assistant' appears that allows a user to cycle through form elements with the 'next' and 'previous' buttons.

This is causing a problem for us where there are two forms on the page:

Once the user reaches the last text field of the first form, if they press 'next' it then jumps to the second form.

Is there a way of making the form assistant only cycle between elements in a single form?